# Rewrite rule not functioning for pagination

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have all my rewrite rules functioning except the one for my pagination.

here is what I have tried: I removed all rewrites except the pagination-fail, I have tried about 50 different rewrites from the web all have failed.. I tried a rewrite generator failed.

my pagination works as follows

```
http://example.com/list.php?p=1
```

now my rewrite is as follows

```
RewriteRule ^([^/][0-9]*)$ list.php?p=$1
```

> htacess

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


RewriteRule ^list/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ list.php?page=$1
```

When I go to `http://example.com/list/p1` I get a 500 error

I have removed a lot of db code since everything but the pagination url rewrite works. reguardless of how I write the links or mod rewrite it does not work I have followed about 50 example none worked.. however all the other rewrites I have wrote for other pages work fine.

```
 <div class="large-centered">  

    <?php   

    $per_page = 2;

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {

        $page = $_GET['page'];
    } else {

        $page = "";
    }

    if ($page == "" || $page == 1) {

        $page_1 = 0;
    } else {

        $page_1 = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;
    }    

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); 
    $count = $stmt->num_rows;

    if ($count < 1) {

        echo "No Users";

    } else {

        $count = ceil($count / $per_page);

        $stmt = $db->prepare("            
            SELECT users.ID, users.Name, users.GroupID, locations.LocationCode, locations.LocationFlag 
            FROM users, locations
            WHERE users.Location = locations.LocationCode AND GroupID != 1 ORDER BY users.ID DESC LIMIT $page_1, $per_page");               
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result(); 
        $stmt->close();


      ?> 
      <div class="pagin-nav"> 
            <ul class="pagination">
            <?php        
                    $number_list = array();        
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i ++) {

                        if ($i == $page) {

                            echo "<li><a class='active' href='list.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";

                        }  else {

                            echo "<li><a href='list.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";

                        }
                    }        
                ?>                   
             </ul>  
        </div><?php 

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $ID = $row['ID'];
            $GroupID = $row['GroupID'];     
            $Name = $row['Name'];          

            if ($GroupID != 1) { 


             //My HTML and output
             echo '<div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-3 end pad">html</div>';

            } else {

                return true;
     } } } ?>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pagin-nav"> 
        <ul class="pagination">
        <?php        
            $number_list = array();        
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i ++) {

                if ($i == $page) {

                    echo "<li><a class='active' href='list.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>"; 

                }  else {

                    echo "<li><a href='list.php?page={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";

                }
            }        
            ?>        
         </ul>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is this directive being used? "but if I do" - you seem to have stopped mid sentence?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^list/p?(\d*)/?$ list.php?p=$1 [L]`

Comment: @Deadooshka I have tried that and about 50 others no rewrite seems to work for this even if I type in the path to it all my other rewrites work fine this one just wont work

Comment: here `href=list.php?p={$i}'` must be `href='/list.php?p={$i}'` or `href='/list/p{$i}'`. Note, all html paths w/o a front slash will be relative to /list/.

Comment: @Deadooshka I can add the full path http: and all it still gives error I am updating to show all my code

Comment: Show your full `.htaccess` file (I assume you're using `.htaccess`?). If "all your other rewrites work fine" then maybe you have a conflict? Order matters.

Comment: @w3dk I added it

Comment: I removed all other rewrite it still did the same thing..

Comment: would like to look an error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `MultiViews` and include this directive *before* the rule that appends the `.php` file extension.

Since `/list` maps to the basename of a physical (ie. `list.php`), `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) will give you problems (it does exactly what you are trying to do with mod_rewrite and will result in a conflict).

For example, in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^list/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ list.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Also include the `L` (`last`) flag on the `RewriteRule`.

Note that this will rewrite `/list/p1` to `/list.php?page=p1`.

Comment: where did you get list.php?page=p1

Comment: That's what the directive does that I copied from your code snippet. Should this go to `list.php?page=1` instead or `list.php?p=1` (which is what you stated at the start of your question)?

Comment: can you help me on this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895224/make-htaccess-rule-apply-only-to-the-current-folder